# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality - proof

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I saw this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/dot-cross-products/v/proof-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality) about the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The proof has be done by constructing an artificial function

$$ p(t)=\left\| t \vec{v}- \vec {u}\right\|^2 $$

and then this function was evaluated in

$$p \left( \frac{b}{2a} \right) $$

Why is the function constructed like this. The point where the function is evaluated is when the determinant is zero. Why?

Comment: What's a non-artificial function?

Comment: I only use cage free, organic, free range functions.

Comment: Sorry, what is a proper terminology? Helpful function?

Comment: @Lukáš Altman just function

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης I think I know what he means. E.g. in German, there is the notion of a „Hilfsfunktion“ (means something along the lines of „helper function“, „utility function“), which isn't really a formal term, but is used to hint at the role of that function in a proof.